# I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine and I want to install Windows 10 alongside it, but I don't have a USB or disk; how can I do this?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I want to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10, and I don't have a USB or CD, and was wondering if I can still install Windows, and if so, how do I do it?

I'm wanting Windows for Windows-only graphics-heavy software (eg Unity, Unreal Engine etc) and Microsoft Office.

Comment: Isn't it usual to do this the other way about? Install Ubuntu on a Windows system. If you only have a few windows apps you want to use, why not install Wine from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: Probbably it is possible to [boot the installation ISO by GRUB](https://www.google.bg/search?ei=Ku7NWt3rDIGS6ATd4rCwDA&q=ubuntu+how+to+boot+iso+from+grub&oq=ubuntu+how+to+boot+iso+from+grub&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6500.13518.0.13852.16.16.0.0.0.0.106.1488.14j2.16.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.miV2zfdy_zo).

Comment: Do you mean your machine doesn't have usb or cd hardware, or that you don't have Windows install media? If the latter, buy it. Or download one of the short-term eval versions from MS.

Comment: Seems to me to be a hardware or Windows problem? "if I can still install Windows and how do I do it?" is not something we can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- buy or borrow a USB pendrive, size 8 GB or more,

---

- create and boot into an Ubuntu live system (from USB),
- use **gparted** to shrink some partition and create unallocated drive space for Windows,

---

- download a Windows iso file from a Microsoft link,
- use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a Windows install USB drive,
- boot from the Windows install drive,
- install Windows, which overwrites Ubuntu's bootloader 'grub',

---

- [repair/reinstall the bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System).

---

In order to make Windows fully functional, you need a Windows license key (which you might find on a sticker on the computer, otherwise buy a license). The key must match the version of Windows, that you install.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from network boot agent but for that system needs to be in a network.

AFAIK, there is no other possible solution to install windows alongside ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bootable media from another working Windows installation. I think Windows 10 can easily be installed with that method.

However i recommend installing Ubuntu after Windows 10, because the default installer of Ubuntu recognizes Windows 10 and creates a boot entry for it along Ubuntu, as in comparison for Windows 10 you will have to create a boot entry for Ubuntu manually.